# Can a trigger be temporary ignored in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Say table `B` has a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger. However, in some cases, I hope the trigger is disabled when I try to delete something from `B`, is that possible?

Comment: There is no out of the box solution for that, but there are ways to achieve it. Googling a little will give you sufficient results (takes 5 seconds to find it actually).

Comment: `some cases` what is this cases ?

Comment: @samitha For example, a trigger in table A will try to delete something in table B, then a trigger in table B will also try to delete something in table A. I can do some check before deleting, but that's ineffective.

Comment: if you have a specific condition to do so we can add that condition to trigger

Comment: Yes, you need to apply a flag to your connection/request statement, and check it inside the trigger in order to ignore or do the business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert a conditional verification (if) inside your trigger to check whether the conditions which will do the actions will be executed or not

e.g:

```
create trigger ai_eav after insert on eav
for each row begin
    set @id=new.entity;
    set @attribute=new.attribute;
    set @value=new.value;

    if n > m then
        update pivot set 
            Author=(select if(@attribute='Author',@value,Author)),
            Title=(select if(@attribute='Title',@value,Title)),
            Publisher=(select if(@attribute='Publisher',@value,Publisher))
        where id=@id;
    end if
end
```

you can find the syntax of mysql if statements here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

this solution is probably much more performatic than deleting and recreating the trigger

Answer (score 0):

For v5.*:
http://www.ehow.com/how_10027479_disable-triggers-mysql.html

Just drop and re-create the trigger.

For v7.0:
http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2825

ALTER TRIGGER ... ENABLE | DISABLE

### Implementation in C:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRIGGER_NAME "testtrigger"
int delete_without_trigger(MYSQL *conn,char *sql) {
  if (mysql_query(conn, "SHOW CREATE TRIGGER " TRIGGER_NAME)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          return -1;
  }
  MYSQL_RES *res=mysql_use_result(conn);
  MYSQL_ROW row= mysql_fetch_row(res);
  char *trigger=strdup(row[2]);
  //printf("TRIGGER==============\n%s\n===========\n",trigger);
  mysql_free_result(res);
  if (mysql_query(conn, "DROP TRIGGER " TRIGGER_NAME)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          return -2;
  }
  if (mysql_query(conn, sql)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          return -3;
  }
  if (mysql_query(conn, trigger)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          return -4;
  }
  free(trigger);
  return 0;
}//delete_without_trigger
```

### Testing:

```
int i;
for(i=99;--i>0;) {
  printf("%d\n",i);
  if(delete_without_trigger(conn,"DELETE FROM syslog WHERE txt='test'")) {
          fprintf(stderr, "handling ERROR\n");
          exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the 2nd solution before asking the question, but it's a shame that I'm not using v7.0. drop and re-create seems so complex, is there any better solution?

Comment: @andre 's solution is faster, if you want to disable the trigger often. I included the actual C code in my solution, it handles only 10-20 requests per second on a Pentuim4 server.